# How to identify this coin with a bust on one side and the letters S and C on the other side?

Tags: ancient-history, ancient-rome, numismatics

I believe this coin is Roman but I'd like that confirmed. Can anyone give an approximate date and any other information possible (maybe difficult as it is quite worn). It measures between 2.5cm and 2.7cm in diameter.

[image: Head]

[image]

I'd also be interested to know (if possible) what it could have bought at the time (e.g. a loaf of bread?, a pair of shoes?).

---

**-----------EDIT------------**

Examining the coin in bright light under a magnifying glass, one can detect more than in the photos. Specifically, one can see 4 letters (circled below).

[image: letters on coin]

There are two letters inside the yellow circle **AV**, presumably the first two letters of 'AUGUSTUS', though I'm not sure this helps much.

Perhaps more useful are the letters in the white and blue circles. These letters look too far apart to be from the same word. The one inside the white circle looks like 'T' while the one inside the blue circle could be **P**, **R** or possibly even **B**.

If the second letter is **R**, I'm wondering if the two letters in the white and blue circles could be the first two letters of **T R P** (TRIBUNICIA POTESTATE)...

Comment: It was given to me by an uncle 20 or 25 years ago. All he said was that it was from the time of the Roman empire.

Comment: It is Roman. The S.C. on the reverse stands for "Senatus Consulto" ("supported by the decree of the Senate") which was common on bronze coins from 27BC to 376AD. My first thought for the portrait on the obverse was Gaius, but it is so badly worn it's hard to be sure.

Comment: @LarsBosteen I would guess it is a dupondius then, which coincidentally actually is about the price of a loaf of bread.

Comment: Although we prefer the less worn coins, consider how many hands have touched this! This is the essence of numismatics: a common-place item, used, as the answer indicates, to buy bread by an unknown and unknowable person more than 2000 years ago. Never sell this, make sure a young person in your family who appreciates it gets it someday!

Comment: @Jeff. Love your comment. The real value of the coin lies in imagining the people who used it.

Comment: In addition to size, the weight of a coin is useful identifying information. If you can weigh it to a precision of 0.1g then the weight would be worth adding to the question.

Comment: I don't have a way of getting that kind of precision (in fact, I don't have any scales at all!). I did consider the weight but the coin is very worn, especially a round the edges, so I'm not sure that giving the weight wouldn't just mislead.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Although the coin is quite worn, you can clearly on the reverse the inscription `S C`, meaning [*senatus consulto*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Senatus_consultum). This confirms that it is a Roman coin and probably one from an early period.

Based on the size and colour, your coin could be a [dupondius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dupondius) which was worth 2 [as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As_(Roman_coin)) or 1/8 of a [denarius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denarius). In the early imperial period, this buy you perhaps one to two loafs of baked bread depending on the local prices.

The busts on most Roman coins face the right, so this is somewhat uncommon, and further points to something [pre-Severan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Septimius_Severus). It's hard to positively identify without inscriptions, though the obverse - to me anyway - looks rather similar to the Divus Augustus on this coin issued under [Titus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titus):

[image]

The figure on the reverse is too worn to be identifiable, but the position of "S C" fits several designs including Sicilia, Felicita, Aequitas, Victoria, Ceres, and Pax.

[image]
<sup>Example: Sicilia, wearing triskelis, standing left, holding crown and poppies</sup>

In general, the name of the figure depicted is inscribed on the left edge. The apparent lack of letters around the possible P for instance may suggest this might be Pax, though that doesn't explain the possible T character to its lower right.

Note that distance between letters does **not** prove they're from different words. It is quite common for letters to spaced far apart or unevenly, especially for shorter words.

[image]
<sup>Example: Pax, draped and holding branch cornucopia. Notice how the X is extremely distant from PA.</sup>

Comment: According to [this site](http://www.forumancientcoins.com/dougsmith/abb.html) this most commonly occurred on bronze coins, which may help narrow the search (and provide some value information).

Comment: I am accepting this answer as, although I don't think it is Titus, there is a lot of other useful information which really helped me find what I think is the answer.

Comment: @LarsBosteen Oh, I meant the coin was issued during Titus's reign, not that it depicts Titus (Divus Augustus is the deified persona of Augustus). But I agree with you, it does look like an unbearded Antoninus Pius. What a rare find!

Comment: Apologies for the misunderstanding :)

Answer (score 11):

After trawling through hundreds of coin images, I am reasonably sure that the emperor depicted in the coin in the question is **Antoninus Pius** (138 - 161 AD).

In the compilation below, the **top left coin is the one in the questio**n. The **other coins are all confirmed as Antoninus Pius**.

[image: Antoninus Pius]

Sources: https://www.ma-shops.com/roman-empire/antoninus-pius/?catid=717&lang=en&ajax=2z6
http://www.wildwinds.com/coins/ric/antoninus_pius/i.html

One thing that made identification difficult is that most Antoninus Pius coins show him with beard (perhaps to hide the rather prominent chin?).

Comment: I should add that without Semaphore's post and various helpful comments, I doubt if I would have been able find this (at least, not for another year or two...).

Answer (score 8):

Very difficult to identify, but pretty surely a "Claudius", many of them faced to the left, and the profile is very similar. Alas, hints don't help much...

What you think as "**AU**gustus" can be "AVG" (shortcut for AUGUSTUS of course). For blue/white circles that could be LIBERTAS.

[image: face]
[image: back face]

Look at [comptoir-des-monnaies.com](http://www.comptoir-des-monnaies.com/product_info.php/claudius-as-4150-roma-ttb-cuivre-cohen47-ric97-p-415726?language=fr) or maybe [comptoir-des-monnaises.com](http://www.comptoir-des-monnaies.com/product_info.php/claude-ier-as-cohen-47-p-60604?language=fr).